# Managed package status shows expired, how can i renew it?

Tags: appexchange, licenses, developer-edition, lma

We have a managed package in appexchange which has expired for a customer. I want to understand if we can renew this package from our end, also we have a salesforce developer edition.
I know we can do it by LMA but can we install it in developer edition?

Comment: Your LMA (license management app) should be installed in your BPO (business production organization). You can control the number of licenses and status from there. You should not install the LMA in a developer edition org.

Comment: For my production account it shows  Organization Edition as Developer Edition, So can i install LMA there?